# What data type is the json file content in R language?

Tags: r, json

I have a json file on my computer.
Is my output a dictionary or list or string?

Below is my code in Rstudio:

```r
install.packages("rjson")
library("rjson")
output <- fromJSON(file = "provdata.json")
```

Comment: JSON files are text files, `output` is whatever is in that specific instance of the JSON format, your data.

Comment: More generally, you can inspect an R object's structure with `str`, find out about its class with `class`, its internal storage mode with `typeof`. R does not have Pythonic dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

*It depends* on the json content.

```r
## vector
rjson::fromJSON('[1,2,3]')
# [1] 1 2 3

## list
rjson::fromJSON('[1,2,3]', simplify = FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# [[3]]
# [1] 3

## another list
rjson::fromJSON('[[1,2,3]]')
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3

## dictionary, aka named-list
rjson::fromJSON('{"a":1,"b":2}')
# $a
# [1] 1
# $b
# [1] 2
```